# Given a line of code, count the number of steps corresponding to the execution

Tags: python

I have a code as such:

[image]

and what i have to do is to count the number of steps in the code during execution.

The instructions are as such where:

[image]

the solution provided that the total number of steps is 2 + 3 ∗ (2 + 3 ∗ 3 + 2) + 2 = 43

i understand that the first two line of code gives me 2 since assignment counts as one time step. however, I'm lost at the part with the while loop. Could someone please break it down to me and explain a little?

Comment: not clear with your question. What do you want actually ?

Comment: I'd recommed to replace graphics by real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should start be analyzing the second while loop :

```
while j < 3:
    total = total + 1
    j = j + 1
```

Each time you execute this loop, you run two assignements. So each loop takes two steps. Well, let's see what we can get :

1. j = 0 -> 1 step for comparison + 2 step for assignements
2. j = 1 -> 1 step for comparison + 2 step for assignements
3. j = 2 -> 1 step for comparison + 2 step for assignements
4. j = 3 -> 1 step for comparison only (we do not enter the loop)

So, it takes 3*3 + 1 = 10 steps to complete this process. Now, let's look at the bigger while loop :

```
while i < 3:
    j = 0
    while j < 3:
       ...
    i = i + 1
```

Like before, here we do 10 + 2 + 1 = 13 operations each valid loop, and one operation for the last comparison. So, in the end, it takes 3*13 + 1 to completely go throughout the loop. Finally, you get 1 step for the return, and two steps for the initialization : 2 + 3*13 + 1 + 1 = 43.

I hope it answers your question !

Comment: ah perfect. Thanks a bunch. I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

```
total = 0       #1
i = 0           #1
# 3 times the following <O>
while i < 3     #probably 1
    j = 0       #1
    # 3 times the following <I>
    while j<3   #probably 1
        total = total + 1   #1
        j = j + 1 #1
    # </I>  
    i = i+1 #1
</O>    
return total #1
```

- I : 3 * (1+1+1) = 9
- O : 3 * (1+1+9+1) = 36
- all: 1+1+36+1 = 39

This is a typical queation for microcontrollers with assembler code, in my opinion it is not useful for python or any other higher language.
It seems to be for didactic reasons.

For me it is unclear, why the inner loop should take 3 cycles (while and 2 Assignments with addition) and the outer loop has theses 3*3 and takes 4 more (for nearly the same 3 statements)

More help you only get from the teacher, who gave you the task.